# Stop CodeBuild projects from running automatically after cloudformation stack deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

When I create a codeBuild project, and integrate it into CodePipeline using Cloudformation, the build automatically triggers when I deploy the cloudFormation stack using serverless framework. I want to trigger the build manually, not automatically.

Is there anyway to stop this default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`Triggers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codebuild-project.html#cfn-codebuild-project-triggers) property in your CodeBuild CFN template and set `Webhook` to false:

```
{
  "BuildType" : String,
  "FilterGroups" : [ FilterGroup, ... ],
  "Webhook" : False
}
```

Comment: This does not work, probably because it only applies to GitHub hosted repositories, but my source is on CodeCommit